# Concatenation of multiple ternary operator in PHP? unexpected ')'

Tags: php, if-statement, ternary-operator

I'm working on a CodeIgniter project but having a problem when using ternary operator, I have this code:

```
<?php echo (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : ((isset($success)) ? $success : ((isset($failed)) ? $failed)); ?>
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'
```

Once I comment that line out, the page loads fine.

What could be the issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Missing the `else` part for last operation.

Comment: `<?php echo (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : ((isset($success)) ? $success : ((isset($failed)) ? $failed :'')); ?>`

Comment: Thanks Sougata and @Anant for the answer. I solved the issue. I searched but didn't find my answer.